# How to set a default war in GlassFish 3.0.1 Community Edition?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

Now I have several wars and each runs when typing in browser 
localhost:8080/app1 
or 
localhost:8080/app2
etc.

When I type http://localhost:8080, appears only the default page.
I want to make app1 as default app, i.e. it must appear when typing
localhost:8080
and others apps as secondary i.e. they must appear when typing localhost:8080/app2.
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying manually through the Admin Console, the context root will (by default) be set to the name of the .war.

You can override this in the "Deploy  Web Application" screen.  You'll want to change the value of the "Context Root" input to `/` after selecting your .war but before clicking "OK".

Answer (score 2):

In admin panel: Configuration → VirtualServers. Select “server” (or current default). Populate the 'default web module' select. Save.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me.  This answer did. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a context-root node in WEB-INF/[sun-web.xml](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4502/beaql?l=en&a=view).

From http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/sundocs/articles/urlrdn.jsp:

```
<sun-web-app>
<context-root>/mywarname</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

My guess would be that saying just `/` will make it the root application.

(Note that the mechanism is different when deploying inside an EAR)